# Partition data while preserving groups with caret

Tags: r, r-caret, train-test-split

Apologies for the cross-stack post, I wasn't sure if this is more appropriate for *stackoverflow* or for *crossvalidated*.  I initiatlly posted on the latter, but realized this might be the more appropriate place.

So, I have a dataset with many rows of individuals, each with a unique indvidual `ID`.

For each individual, there is also a column indicating whether or not that person belongs to the same household, which is a unique `householdID`.

Finally, there is a `Target` variable, for each row, which is what I will be trying to make predictions on. Of course, there are columns with different features.

My question is--as the membership to different households is important--is there a way to partition the data into train and test sets where all the people belonging to the same household are kept together and not randomly split over both sets?  (i.e., any given `householdID` number should not appear in both sets).  But also, it is possible to split the households over both train and test sets and keep a balanced `Target` variable?

So, using the `createDataPartition` function in `caret`, I've managed to have a blanced `Target` value in both train and test when I set `y = Target`, and I've managed to separate the households cleanly over both train and test when I set `y = unique(householdID)`, but I can't figure out if there's a way to get both of these results at the same time.

I'm pretty flat out of ideas, so any suggestions would be most welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: This is called blocking (by householdID). It is hard to do a stratified split based on y and also block by another variable without manual intervention. I suggest concentrating only on the blocking. Do a bunch of splits with different seeds and check the target in each. Then pick one that is the most balanced. If you would like further help please provide some data to play with.

Comment: Thanks @missuse for the suggestion.  Not having seen any other approach, I will try what you suggest as it should be doable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`groupKFold` is the way to go. But instead of using data$Target you need to split on  data$householdID (or whatever your household ID column is named). This will make sure that all members of a group will be in the same fold.

After this you can use the folds in `trainControl` to model on data$Target.

Comment: Hi @phiver, thanks for the suggestion, but you mention members of the group being in the same fold, which is the part that confuses me about the `groupKFold` function--namely, is this function only to be used for making k-folds of the data for CV purposes?  In my case, I'm trying to do my initial split of the data into a train and test set, where no `householdID` values appear in both sets, but also the `Target` variable is balanced across both.  Does that make sense?